# How to add list view as a link in salesforce1?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a requirement where I need to add particular list view as a link in salesforce1 navigation menu.

So to achieve that I created a VF page and added the list view as shown below and also added Visualforce tab in the salesforce1 navigation menu.

```
<apex:enhancedlist type=”Opportunity” height=”730″ customizable=”false” rowsPerPage=”25″ Listid=”00B30000007wesH” />
```

Whenever user clicks on the VF tab it should open the List view in the form of Salesforce1 list view as shown below not like desktop version.

Image for Salesforce1 list view :

[image]

But it is showing like this :

[image]

How to achieve the expected one ? can anyone please suggest me ?

Comment: why did you use `apex:enhancedList` ?  does `apex:relatedList` not work for you?

Comment: @cropredy I want to display list view not related list and also i tried using `<apex:ListViews type="Opportunity" />` but still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using Lightning App Builder.

I created a Lightning App and added Filter List (Opportunity list view)